# Identifying Universities mentioned in Tweet Text

Tags: twitter, nlp, named-entity-recognition, apache-stanbol

I am looking for a means of identifying UK University names mentioned in Tweet text.

I have a list of full University names, but the issue is dealing with shortened versions such as "aber uni" (Aberystwyth Uni), "staffs uni" (Staffordshire University) or "portsmouth" (University of Portsmouth).

I have looked down the route of Apache Stanbol and OpenNLP to attempt Named Entity Recognition, and although these will match for the full names I cannot seem to find a means of training them to identify variations of the names (or indeed lowercase versions of the name which are not identified).

Answer (score 0):

Gather a list of universities (which is easy to do) and scrape the list of names for each university from Freebase: 
[What is one way to find related names using the web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317095/what-is-one-way-to-find-related-names-using-the-web/24320476#24320476)