# how to automatically detect acronym meaning / extension

Tags: nlp, information-extraction, acronym

How can you detect / find out the meaning (the extension) of an acronym using NLP / Information Extraction (IE) methods?

We want to detect in free text if a word or it's acronym is used and map it to the same entity / token.

Most papers available online are about medical acronyms and they do not provide a library for acomplish this task.

Any ideas?

Comment: Acronyms are almost always domain dependent. That is why it is not a good idea to have a "general" library. NLP, for example, could mean 'natural language processing' or 'neuro-linguistic programming', depending on the domain.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You mean, given a word, you want to find its acronym?

Comment: @Daniel yes I mean a mapping which maps the acronym to the extension

Comment: @ChthonicProject yes I understand that it is domain dependent. But how can I create such a (domain specific) mapping using NLP / text mining

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading your question and the comments I understand that you want to create a mapping from an acronym to its extension.

Assuming you have a collection of textual documents where both the acronym and its expansion occur you can apply an algorithm to extract (acronym,extension) pairs.

[A Simple Algorithm for Identifying Abbreviation Definitions in Biomedical Text](http://biotext.berkeley.edu/papers/psb03.pdf) by A.S Schwartz and M.A. Hearst, does exactly this by looking at patterns. The Java implementation is available [here](http://biotext.berkeley.edu/code/abbrev/).

I applied this algorithm to the English Wikipedia, you can see the results [here](https://github.com/davidsbatista/lexicons/blob/master/wikipedia-acronyms.txt). I also applied it to a collection of Portuguese new articles, results are [here](https://github.com/davidsbatista/lexicons/blob/master/publico-acronyms.txt).

Comment: There also is a Python implementation: http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/~vincent/scripts/abbreviations.py

Answer (score 0):

Wordnet contains acronym for tons of words which you can use in variety of programming languages: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/

Or get from Freebase. See this: [What is one way to find related names using the web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317095/what-is-one-way-to-find-related-names-using-the-web)

Comment: In my experience Wordnet contains very few acronyms. For example, UN, NATO and AA are there, but ISO, CERN, YMCA, CCTV, ... are not.