# How to refine text data?

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk, text-mining

I built many spiders to get news articles from different websites and i have an api to convert the text to audio clips, but i need a framework or python tools to refine the articles' text such as:

> removing anything related to the source. removing any dates formats.
>   removing urls. change acronyms such as CEO to chief excution officer
>   for example. removing special characters and typos.

making sure that the sentence is written correctly after all the edits.
use the previously edited articles as a reference for the new articles.

I am using python, nltk and re, but it's exhausting and each time i think i covered all the cases, i find new cases to add and i think i am stuck in an infinite loop.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [expanding acronyms to their full form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26716622/1391325) is non-trivial and should probably not be considered part of scraping but rather part of a second step of processing (cf. [IBM's *The Art of Tokenization*](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/nlp/entry/tokenization?lang=en)).

Cleaning scraped data is tedious, unfortunately: There is no magical solution because everyone is interested in scaping something different than what you are — some might be interested *only* in URLs, for example. Nevertheless, have you not tried using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)? — it's a Python library which offers a very nice API for handling many common scraping-related tasks.